# call method in different from @selector in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, selector

How do we call a method which is in classB from @selector tag of classA.??

Can i do it in this way??

```
[tis_obj authenticate:self action:@selector([classB method]:)
              accName:@"BOOK" User:@"User"];
```

Is there a possibility to call a method of different class form@selector tag?? or should the method be always in same class?

Thank You.

Answer (score 4):

No you can't. To call a `-[classB method:]`, the authenticate: parameter must have a classB instance, e.g.

```
classB* b = [[clasB alloc] init];
[tis_obj authenticate:b action:@selector(method:) …];
self.b = b;
[b release];
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you want `tis_obj` to use the `method` selector on `classB`. I'm not sure what `tis_obj` is, but I see you're passing an argument `self` there. Perhaps what you're really looking for is:

```
[tis_obj authenticate:classB
               action:@selector(method:)
              accName:@"BOOK"
                 User:@"User"];
```

This will presumably mean that `tis_obj` will at one point perform the equivalent of `[classB method:someArg]`.

Answer (score 1):

A selector is just a name. The selector in the method call `[someObject foo:5]` is just `foo:`. It doesn't specify a method or a receiver, just the name.

Answer (score 1):

What you pass to @selector() doesn't have a class name. A selector definition is simply a method name, so this will work:

```
[tis_obj authenticate:self action:@selector(method:)
          accName:@"BOOK" User:@"User"];
```

(if "method:" is defined on your class of course)